# Managing logins on a framework only SilverStripe site

Tags: silverstripe

I'm currently toying around with making a framework-only `SilverStripe` site and so far so good - I've set up a controller and some models and all is well there, however I'm having issue with creating a login system.

It seems the `$Form` variable that normally displays the login form when you visit `/admin` doesn't display anything. Should it? I thought that it would, however it is not doing.

I guess my question is - do framework only sites use the default login form, and if so what are the first steps to troubleshoot why the form is not showing on my site? Could it have something to do with routes?

Here is my code:

Routes.yml

```
---
Name: app
After: 'framework/routes'
---
Director:
  rules:
    '': 'GanttController'
    '$URLSegment//$Action/$ID/$OtherID': 'GanttController'
```

GanttController.php

```
<?php

class GanttController extends BaseController {

    public function index() {
        return $this->customise(new ArrayData(array(
            'Title' => 'Gantt Chart'
        )))->renderWith(array(
            'GanttController',
            'Page'
        ));
    }
```

Page.ss

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>$Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Gantt</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="pane">
            $Layout
            $Form
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I add the line `'admin': 'AdminRootController'` to my YAML routes and go to `/admin`, instead of it loading up my project it loads up the `get started with the SilverStripe framework` page, where it links you to the docs on adding controllers/templates.

Answer (score 0):

the framework should display the $Form given that you have a template that uses it.

the framework is still designed to have a frontend, this means to 2 things:

1. framework will use templates/Page.ss as default template for frontend as usual
2. if you want the admin / or the secuirty login form, you need to access this controller
   you can do this 3 ways:

   - access it via the already existing route: `/admin` or `/Security/login?backURL=/the/url/to/redirect/to/after/login`
   - use a http redirect make `/` redirect to `/admin`
   - if you don't want a frontend at all, you just use `Page.ss` for the login template and make `/` to show the same thing as `/admin` by assiging the route `/` to the `AdminRootController` with the following yml config:

File: mysite/_config/routes.yml

```
---
Name: mysiteroutes
Before: '*'
After:
  - '#rootroutes'
  - '#coreroutes'
  - '#modelascontrollerroutes'
  - '#adminroutes'
---
Director:
  rules:
    '': 'AdminRootController'
```

---

if this does not answer your question and you still can't get the form to display, please paste your code (your route configs, your Page.ss, and any relevant Controller you might have).

Comment: hmm, template looks OK. what do you see if you visit `/Security/login`, also try to create a file `templatex/Secuirty.ss` with a `$Form` in it, this way SilverStripe should use this template instead of `Page.ss` for the login form. (also, don't forget to `?flush=1`)

Comment: shouldn't there be a `Security::permissionFailure()` in a controller's index or somewhere, so SilverStripe knows this needs login to access? Otherwise the login form will not be displayed?

Comment: going directly to `/Security/login` does the same as going to `/admin` with the framework only intro page. Is it possible to ?flush when you arent logged in as an admin? Atm emptying `silverstripe-cache` in the file system has been my makeshift flush...

Comment: Also FYI I cant `/dev/build`, I get `Website Error
There has been an error
The website server has not been able to respond to your request.` currently building manually with `$db->build()`

Comment: If your site is in dev mode, you should be able to flush without being logged in. But if you can't build your site the "normal" way, there might be a bigger underlying problem?!

Comment: Bahhh I forgot to include dev mode in my site configuration! What a schoolboy error... `dev/build` is now working, however `/admin` is not. `dev/build` only works with `'dev': 'DevelopmentAdmin'` in my `routes.yml`, I have `'admin': 'AdminRootController'` in there too however it doesnt seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Fixed it: if my `routes.yml` has nothing but `'': 'GanttController'` in it, login & dev both work as expected. My next question now would be, how do I handle 404's cleaner if I don't have a route to a controller there to catch it? If I go to an invalid url it just spits out `No URL rule was matched`

Comment: glad you got it working. for a new question,please open a new one to keep the issues separated and making it easier to find for others with the same question